CookieAuthenticationHandler middleware is skipped when the SignedOutCallbackPath of OpenIdConnectOptions is set to an existing controller action route
I started looking into an issue where one of the endpoints exposed by an ASP.NET application (.NET 6) shows a blank page instead of showing the actual view or redirecting to the login page in case an authentication cookie is not set.
Until I realized that this is caused by setting the SignedOutCallbackPath to the same endpoint when configuring the OpenID Connect:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".MyIdp";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options);
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/status/";
        // other settings goes here
    });

Navigating to /status works as expected and the action is being hit, but navigating to /status/ doesn't hit the actual endpoint, and a blank page is presented.
Changing the options.SignedOutCallbackPath to any other value, restores the default behavior- where the endpoint is reachable via both /status and /status/.
Here are the logs generated when I navigate to /status/:

2024-05-08
15:32:47.9351|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request
starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5005/status/ - - 2024-05-08
15:32:47.9539|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware|Allowed
hosts: localhost;  2024-05-08
15:32:47.9539|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware|Allowed
hosts: localhost;  2024-05-08
15:32:47.9539|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|The request path /status/ does not match a supported file type 2024-05-08
15:32:48.0128|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1
candidate(s) found for the request path '/status/' 2024-05-08
15:32:48.0156|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|Endpoint 'MyApplication.Controllers.StatusController.Status (MyApplication)'
with route pattern 'status' is valid for the request path '/status/'
2024-05-08
15:32:48.0156|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request
matched endpoint 'MyApplication.Controllers.StatusController.Status
(MyApplication)' 2024-05-08
15:32:48.1373|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections|Connection
id "0HN3FBBRVV0BB" completed keep alive response. 2024-05-08
15:32:48.1390|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request
finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5005/status/ - - - 200 0 -
205.2468ms

and the logs when navigating to /status:

2024-05-08
15:34:05.1178|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request
starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5005/status - - 2024-05-08
15:34:05.1178|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|The request path /status does not match a supported file type 2024-05-08
15:34:05.1178|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1
candidate(s) found for the request path '/status' 2024-05-08
15:34:05.1178|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|Endpoint 'MyApplication.Controllers.StatusController.Status (MyApplication)'
with route pattern 'status' is valid for the request path '/status'
2024-05-08
15:34:05.1178|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request
matched endpoint 'MyApplication.Controllers.StatusController.Status
(MyApplication)' 2024-05-08
15:34:05.1294|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme:
Cookies was not authenticated. 2024-05-08
15:34:05.1294|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService|Authorization
failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2024-05-08
15:34:05.5091|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler|HandleChallenge
with Location:
https://localhost:5008/connect/authorize?client_id=oidc-MyApplication&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5005%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&code_challenge=removed-for-brevity&code_challenge_method=S256&max_age=1200&nonce=removed-for-brevity&state=removed-for-brevity&x-client-SKU=removed-for-brevity&x-client-ver=6.10.0.0;
and Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.removed=N;
expires=Wed, 08 May 2024 12:49:05 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure;
samesite=none;
httponly,.AspNetCore.Correlation.FQjOnW1jEVgDeQkiDB604qPsjk8mrGaX5MfOe7tMpH0=N;
expires=Wed, 08 May 2024 12:49:05 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure;
samesite=none; httponly. 2024-05-08
15:34:05.5169|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler|AuthenticationScheme:
OpenIdConnect was challenged. 2024-05-08
15:34:05.5169|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections|Connection
id "0HN3FBBRVV0BB" completed keep alive response. 2024-05-08
15:34:05.5169|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request
finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5005/status - - - 302 0 -
409.5968ms

From the logs, it appears that when the endpoint matches exactly the options.SignedOutCallbackPath, the CookieAuthenticationHandler doesn't handle the request as expected, which is required for accessing the protected resource, and shows the blank page (with 200 response code).

Based on my understanding, the "SignedOutCallbackPath" need set accoroding to the specific identity provider like AAD need set tit as  "/signout-oidc". Why you change it to a custom one and looks like the status doesn't contain any logic inside it.
